# Error when filtering pandas dataframe by column value

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am having a problem with filtering a pandas dataframe. I am trying to filter a dataframe based on column values being equal to a specific list but I am getting a length error.

I tried every possible way of filtering a dataframe but got nowhere. Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Here is my code :

```
for ind in df_hourly.index:
    
    timeslot = df_hourly['date_parsed'][ind][0:4] # List value to filter
    filtered_df = df.loc[df['timeslot'] == timeslot]
```

**Error :** ValueError: ('Lengths must match to compare', (5696,), (4,))

**Above Image : df , Below Image : df_hourly**

[image]

In the above image, the dataframe I want to filter is shown. Specifically, I want to filter according to the "timeslot" column.

And the below image shows the the dataframe which includes the value I want to filter by. I specifically want to filter by "date_parsed" column. In the first line of my code, I iterate through every row in this dataframe and assign the first 4 elements of the list value in df_hourly["date_parsed"] to a variable and later in the code, I try to filter the above dataframe by that variable.

Comment: please show us some code with the way you tried it. also some example data what you are trying to achieve would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

When comparing columns using `==`, pandas try to compare value by value - aka does the first item equals to first item, second item to the second and so on. This is why you receive this error - pandas expects to have two columns of the same shape.

If you want to compare if value is inside a list, you can use the `.isin` ([documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)):

```py
df.loc[df['timeslot'].isin(timeslot)]
```

Depends on what `timeslot` is exactly, you might to take `timeslot.values` or something like that (hard to understand exactly without giving an example for your dataframe)

Comment: I tried that method but it returns an empty dataframe. Timeslot variable in my code is a list of integers

Comment: Please give full reproduceable example